# Can these two situations be efficiently distinguished?

Tags: distributions, independence, small-sample

We have N+1 dice, one two-sided and N 6-sided ones. The marginal probability density functions are such that each die is fair, i.e. each face shows up with probability $1/6$.
We want to distinguish two different situations:
H1) The dice are correlated in the following sense. It is possible to write 0s and 1s (at least one!) on the faces of the dice, and that for each throw the sum modulo two is 0.
H2) For any labelling of the dice, the sum modulo two is random, i.e. not constant.

The question is: How many times do we have to throw the dice to distinguish H1 from H2 (with some confidence)? What is the best scaling with respect to N which we could get with methods from statistics?

Now my first approach was to repeat the experiment and try to find the labelling, but that's a hard combinatorical problem. Then I thought that some test of indepence should also do the trick. I know little about statistics, but I found that a Pearson's Chi-squared test could help. Or since we want to do as few experiments as possible maybe I should look into Fisher exact test. I didn't find information on the minimum required sample size, though. And then there are other tests, like kernel statistical tests which look involved, so I would appreciate your take on this before I try to understand the details.

An example of H1:
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
\text{die}_1 &\text{die}_2& \text{die}_3 & \text{probability}\\
 1 & 1 & 4 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 1 & 2 & 4 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 1 & 3 & 3 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 1 & 4 & 1 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 1 & 4 & 2 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 1 & 5 & 5 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 1 & 5 & 6 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 1 & 6 & 5 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 1 & 6 & 6 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 1 & 2 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 2 & 1 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 2 & 2 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 3 & 5 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 3 & 6 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 4 & 4 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 5 & 3 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 6 & 3 & \frac{1}{18} \\
\end{array}$$
Here the labelling $(1,0)$, $(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)$ and $(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)$ for the sides of the first, second and third die, respectively, gives the constant parity of the outcome.

An example of H2:
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
\text{die}_1 &\text{die}_2& \text{die}_3 & \text{probability}\\
 1 & 4 & 4 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 1 & 4 & 5 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 1 & 4 & 6 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 1 & 5 & 4 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 1 & 5 & 5 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 1 & 5 & 6 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 1 & 6 & 4 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 1 & 6 & 5 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 1 & 6 & 6 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 1 & 2 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 1 & 3 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 2 & 1 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 2 & 2 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 2 & 3 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 3 & 1 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 3 & 2 & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 3 & 3 & \frac{1}{18} \\
\end{array}
$$
Here no labelling can be found that gives a constant parity.

Comment: So the models are H0: always get 0. H1: obtain 0 with probability 1/2 or 1 with probability 1/2? It’s the same as, can we test whether a coin has heads on each side by tossing it many times? It’s pretty clear that we have pretty good power to reject H0 when it’s false with only 5 or so flips.

Comment: Each individual die is fair: once you decided which faces to label 0 and which 1 the probability to see 0 will be 1/2. However, the dies are correlated, such that for H1 the last die you throw will show exactly the side that makes the sum modulo two become zero - if you labelled correctly.

Comment: What are you assuming about the individual dice?  Are they fair, for instance?  How does "not possible" translate to "uniformly random"?  (Those two statements do not appear to be equivalent.)

Comment: According to the present answer, you appear to describe a simple problem.  Is that interpretation correct, or are we overlooking some subtle difference?  The effort you make to describe such a complex setting suggests there must be a difference, but what is it?

Comment: @whuber maybe the subtle difference is, that we need to assign 0 and 1 to the faces, while it would be simple if we knew how to label them. But I'm still trying to understand the answer better.

Comment: That doesn't appear to make any difference at all: the assignment of zeros and ones appears irrelevant to the solution.

Comment: One problem with your question is that H2 is not a statistical hypothesis, because it doesn't concern any particular experiment: it concerns some combinatorial (mathematical) possibility rather than something you can observe.  This seems to be a case of trying to ask a question through an analogy that doesn't work.  Could you please just describe your actual problem?

Comment: @whuber The "dice" are actually quantum measurements in my application, but I thought it's easier to ask it without the quantum stuff that produces the distribution.

Comment: I think H2 is the lack of the kind of correlation we see in H1, and my guess was that some kind of independence measure can distinguish the two.

Comment: What information can I add to clarify the question?

Answer (score 2):

So the models are

- $H_0$: always get 0, and
- $H_1$: obtain 0 with probability 1/2 or 1 with probability 1/2.

your question is equivalent to can we test whether a coin has heads on each side by tossing it many times. It’s pretty clear that we have pretty good power to reject $H_0$ when it’s false with only 5 or so flips.

Comment: I don't think this is equivalent to my question, or I do not see how.

Comment: @M.Stern It is. H0 is straightforward, as it's defined so that you always get modulo 0. For H1, every die you roll has a 50% chance of flipping the parity of the modulo from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0, and a 50% chance of keeping it the same. You pointed out in the question itself that you get 0 or 1 with 50% probability under the second scenario, and 0 100% of the time under the first scenario. It doesn't matter if you produce those probabilities by flipping coins or rolling dice.

Comment: oh ok, "always get 0" refers to the parity of all outcomes. Maybe I need just more explanation on how to perform the test, then. Note that it is not obvious whether a face should be labelled 0 or 1. For H1 we only know that such a labelling exists.

Comment: I found that I should not assume uniform randomness in H2, and the probabilities could be different from one half. I hope this edit to the question does not affect your answer (I don't think so, but I also do not understand, yet).